# Senseo & Raspberry PI soldering circuit board

Tags: pcb, raspberry-pi, soldering

I am kinda new to the whole hardware stuff and as an amateur I am working on a little project. I would like to connect my senseo machine to my Raspberry Pi. I've got a senseo HD7810 and a Raspberry Pi 2B.

I've found an online tutorial, but unfortunatly the tutorial is written for another senseo machine. Now I am kinda lost on wich places I should solder the wires.

[image: Senseo HD7810 circuit board]

I've attached a picture of my circuit board. The most left red button is the button for 1 cup of coffee. The middle button is the power switch and the most right button is the 2 cups button.

I'm not quitte sure if I am allowed to post a link directly to the tutorial, so I will just type the instructions:

"Solder your wires to the points on the Senseo board like shown above. As you can see all the white wires are wired to the "bridge" on top of the board. This is the ground and we'll be extending it to the ground of the Pi.

The coloured wires are connected to the other end or positive side of each I/O element. In my case black is soldered to the LED, orange is soldered to the "1-cup" button, red is soldered to the on-off button en green is soldered to the "2-cups" button. Don't wory about the colours, but you should remember or mark down which wires you use for the different I/O elements."

The circuit board used in the tutorial:

[image: circuit board of the tutorial]

Comment: You would probably need to take some time to understand the signals (apparently the switches) used in the original instruction, and find the corresponding ones on your board.  Then you should probably get a voltmeter and verify that the signal voltages on your board are acceptable for whatever you want to control them with (the pi directly, or some intermediate device, you didn't say) as just because they were on one model does not mean they will be on another.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for your response. I'm an absolute beginner with this, so sorry if any information is missing. As i understand from your answer, I should measure the voltage on the board when i push a button? That way i could 'read' wich lines are for a certain instruction?

Comment: No, that is not what I said at all.  First you have to understand the circuit.  Then you need to use a meter to verify that the circuit's voltage is acceptable to your control device.  That's the price of trying to port the project to a different version of the machine.

Comment: Hi Chris! Sorry for the late response. In my enthiousiasm I totally read over it! I am now following Rob's instructions and seeing how that works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your RPi to be able to *press* the 3 buttons on your Senseo device. From the other tutorial it sounds as though this device operates on 3.3V,

I would use a multi-meter measuring for continuity with the device unplugged/off. Prob the two points I have arrows to, if your meter beeps than these would be *shorted* together indicating ground.
[image]

Then I would solder your ground lead to the ground leg on the button to the left. Use your continuity tester to determine ground legs on the other 2 buttons. You will want to solder the wire to the **non-ground** legs on the other buttons. So it **may** look like this...[image]

Then close up your device with your wires ran outside. Strip the ends of these wires and ensure that they are not shorting. Use a multi-meter to measure voltage to each button in reference to your ground wire. Ensure that you are only seeing 3.3V as anything higher will fry your RPi. Let me know if this helps. The second image is my best guess as to how your wires would need to be but with out it in front of me it is just a guess!

Comment: Hi Rob! Many thanks for this detailled answer! I'm now going to try these points and see what the multimeter reads. I'm aware of the 3.3V, as i've already once made my own ambilights. Again, many thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works out!

Comment: Hi Rob. Been working on it, but came accross something wich might be a stupid question.. But do all the buttons need ground wiring? I have soldered the wires as you mentioned. The machine at least still works haha. Now I am going to measure the voltages.

Comment: No as long as you have 1 ground wire that you can connect to RPi you will be set to go. It's more or less a reference to know if the input is high/low. Ex if I tell you a height of 2 meters. It could be a from the ground or from a table top. With grounds connected both devices have the same reference to know the intended value. The ground circuit those buttons are connected to is like a single wire that everything on the PCB uses as a reference so only 1 is needed to connect to Pi.

Comment: Hi Rob. A little update: The soldering went well and both the machine as my pi didn't fry. Wich is already a big achievement for me haha! Unfortunatly the senseo machine didnt respond to any of my signals i sended with the pi. I'm now going to demontage the senseo machine again and going to measure wich points give voltage when the machine is turned on. As it seems that the ground is correct.

Comment: Are you sending a HIGH or LOW signal to the machine? If 1 side of the button is ground I would except the other side to be pulled-up to 3.3V or HIGH.

Comment: I am sending a HIGH signal to the machine. Haven't got time for the measuring, but I will let you know asap!

Comment: Ok, I would send a LOW and see what you get !

Comment: Yeah I've tried both. But I'm guessing the solder points are incorrect

Comment: Hi Rob. Another update... IT WORKS!! After the demontage i saw that one of the solder points wasnt connecting good to it, so I fixed it and it works! Man, cant even tell how happy i am at the moment. Can I atleast buy you a beer for your help?

Comment: Hey glad it works! No need, just pass on knowledge to someone else! Always feels great when your project starts to work out!